# safecopy creates huge image with more block than exist

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive

I had an hdd crash and want to recover data using safecopy. The hdd is of 2TB size and I started safecopy with this command:

`safecopy --stage1 /media/ubuntu/086ACF266ACF0F7E /media/ubuntu/externaldrive/diskimage-stage1.img`

After a few days of printing `XXXXXXXXXX....` the command terminated with this output:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX [1953363484] 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX [1953363525] 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX [1953363566] 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX [1953363607] 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX [1953363648] 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX [1953363689] 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX [1953363730] 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX [1953363771] 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX [1953363812] 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX [1953363853] 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX [1953363894] 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX [1953363935] 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX [1953363976] 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX [1953364017] 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ;-} 0%
Error: write to output failed : No space left on device
}[1953364035](+8000979087360)

Aborted because of error!
Recovered bad blocks: 0
Unrecoverable bad blocks (bytes): 1953364035 (8000979087360)
Blocks (bytes) copied: 1953364034 (8000979083264)
```

This seems a little odd to me because the external harddive I saved the image file is 8TB. However, the image file really seems to be that big:

```
ls -lah /media/ubuntu/externaldrive/ | grep img
-rwxrwxrwx  1 ubuntu ubuntu 7,3T Jan 18 08:06 diskimage-stage1.img
```

And also weird, the block counter of safecopy stopped at `1953364017` but df of the damaged hdd says, there are only `1952950268` blocks:

```
df /media/ubuntu/086ACF266ACF0F7E/
Dateisystem     1K-Blöcke   Benutzt  Verfügbar Verw% Eingehängt auf
/dev/sda2      1952950268 717184952 1235765316   37% /media/ubuntu/086ACF266ACF0F7E
```

I don't understand what happened here. Can anyone help me understanding this? Why is the image of a 2TB hdd growing over 8TB? Am I using safecopy in a wrong way?

Thank you for reading! :)

Comment: Im GUESSING that safecopy is kld and does correctly not handle block sizes other then 512  bytes when writing (man page says its from 2009).  Maybe try again (ideally to another disk - it might be possible to retrieve data from the 8gig partial image by only reading 512/4k - and the copy process may have further damaged the disk) using ddrescue.

Comment: Thanks David for your reply! The .img file is stated to be unreadable, even with isobuster I could not even partially retrieve data. So, I am trying to use ddrescure, but when I run `ddrescue -f -n /media/ubuntu/086ACF266ACF0F7E/ /media/ubuntu/externaldrive/hdd.img` it outputs the block below and exits. Am I doing this wrong or is it just 'too late' to rescue things?

Comment: `GNU ddrescue 1.23
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
     ipos:     7680 B, non-trimmed:        0 B,  current rate:       0 B/s
     opos:     7680 B, non-scraped:     7168 B,  average rate:       0 B/s
non-tried:        0 B,  bad-sector:     1024 B,    error rate:    9216 B/s
  rescued:        0 B,   bad areas:        2,        run time:          0s
pct rescued:    0.00%, read errors:        3,  remaining time:         n/a
                              time since last successful read:         n/a
Finished`

Comment: btw, here is the logfile of ddrescue (sorry for the bad format :/ ):
`# Mapfile. Created by GNU ddrescue version 1.23
# Command line: ddrescue -f -n /media/ubuntu/086ACF266ACF0F7E/ /media/ubuntu/externaldrive/hdd.img /media/ubuntu/externaldrive/ddrescue.log
# Start time:   2019-01-19 11:43:34
# Current time: 2019-01-19 11:43:34
# Finished
# current_pos  current_status  current_pass
0x00002000     +               1
#      pos        size  status
0x00000000  0x00000200  -
0x00000200  0x00001C00  /
0x00001E00  0x00000200  -
`

Comment: I think I see your issue - it looks like you did not copy the block device, rather you tried to copy something else. To do an image of your disk I would  I would simply use       ddrescue **/dev/sda2** /path/to/output.file /path/to/log.file